# Speed and memory benefit from declaring variable outside JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are similar questions for C#, but we didn't see any for JavaScript.

Is it accepted practice to declare variables inside a loop?

Assume a loop of 200 iterations.

Is there a performance imperative (memory and speed) to using sample 2 over sample 1? We're using jQuery to loop. It improves code readability for us to keep the var inside the loop, but we'll switch if it's not a best practice or will result in materially slower performance or higher memory usage.

```
**Sample 1:**
$(this).each( function() {
   var i = $(some_div).clone();
   *** edit i ***
   $(another_div).append( i );
});



**Sample 2:**
var i = null;
*** edit i ***
$(this).each( function() {
   i = $(some_div).clone();
   $(another_div).append( i );
});
```

Comment: @Crashalot: In sample 1, variable is created at each iteration. In sample 2, variable is reused. Have you done some performance tests?

Comment: No, we were curious to hear best practices since this must be an established pattern. We assume there is a performance gain because the var is reused, but wondered if there were significant advantages. It's simpler to read the code if the vars are inside the loop, but if speed and memory performance requires declaring outside, then we will.

Comment: Each implementation could be different. For all you know without further research any given interpreter could optimize it on the fly and remove any penalty.

Comment: One lexical scope lookup vs non closed over variables. I would imagine that the difference would be negligible and vary wildly between browsers. Probably not worth the theoretical performance gain. Write what makes sense.

Comment: Your two samples are not equivalent.

Comment: If performance is an issue you'll get a much more significant improvement by replacing the .each() loop with a conventional for loop. Note that your sample doesn't need the i variable at all: $(another_div).append($(some_div).clone()); - also, without having tested it, I'd expect a performance improvement if you declare variables outside the loop for $(another_div) and $(some_div), rather than creating new jQuery objects in every iteration.

Comment: Each already passes the index to the callback.  See the API doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample 1 (variable inside) is faster:
http://jsperf.com/variable-outside-faster

But the difference is not worth enough to care about.

Comment: we're confused. how is inside faster? isn't it executing an extra operation (declaring variable)? we're also curious on the effect on memory.

Comment: @Crashalot I've seen Paulirish.com using this, I got it from him. I can't explain why it is faster, just tested it.

Comment: Heh, you were faster than me in creating this. Look at "Shorten Scope Chains" in [this article](http://homepage.mac.com/rue/JS_Optimization_Techniques/) for an explanation.

Comment: Declaring a variable isn't an extra operation. Chrome, for instance, compiles that JavaScript to native code before executing. That means it will pre-allocate some memory to the function. I believe when it tries to resolve the variable name, having it in the same scope speeds up the lookup, so the first code ends up faster. But this is just my guess. Anyway, that wouldn't be necessarily true in other implementations, be it other browsers or JavaScript embedded in other environments (JVM, .NET CLI etc).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, thanks for the clarification! didn't know this. btw, this is for mobile safari, so not sure if these optimizations apply.

Comment: @Crashalot I ran that on Safari 5.1 on iOS 5.1: inside is still faster.

Comment: It'd also be a trivial optimisation to completely do away with `i` in sample I --- it could just pass it directly to the `$(...).append` call

Comment: I understand that inside in this case is faster because of scoping, but what about a normal loop like: `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) var tmp = $(something)`. Here it seems declaring the tmp-variable once, outside the loop, would be faster?

Comment: @powerbuoy - JS doesn't have block scope: a var statement inside a for loop is treated as if it was at the top of the current function scope (though the actual assignment happens at the line you put it).

Comment: Ah yes I know it's available outside the `for` loop in that case, my question was more on performance. Edit: because when I saw the title of the OP's question I thought that was what he meant.

Comment: If anything, these tests show that jsperf cannot be trusted at all. The results should be equal because the work actually done in the tests completely shadow **nano** optimizations such as variable declarations. -1 for you and everyone thinking this prooves anything

Comment: I hope you read the part "But the difference is not worth enough to care about."

Answer (score 4):

This is a micro optimization, stop doing that.

Instead invest energy into writing readable code and doing documentation and testing for the code.

However, there are some high level issues that are worth optimizing for:

- Removing bloated abstractions like jQuery that make you an order of magnitude slower.
- Reducing the amount of rendering and drawing you're doing on screen
- Reducing the big O complexity of your algorithms
- Reducing the latency of server-client trips.

Comment: what do you recommend for mobile safari if not jquery?

Comment: Mobile is a resource constrained environment.  Performance matters in some apps.  You don't have enough information to suggest this is not needed.

Comment: @Crashalot you don't need libraries, you use "vanilla javascript"

Comment: I didn't (and don't) downvote, but the expression "Y U hating" made me want to...

Comment: -1 for suggesting focussing on readable code and suggesting replacing jQuery with vanilla JS in the same thread

Comment: @tobyodavies If you need jQuery to write readable code then you need to learn to write readable code

Comment: @Raynos if anyone can write cross-browser JS without dozens of feature/browser detection tests and/or re-implementing most of jQuery that is clearer than the same features implemented with jQuery I'd be impressed. Browser compatibility is a big part of what makes vanilla JS ugly, that and the ugliness of DOM interfaces. It's easy to write vanilla JS that reads how you are doing something, it's much more difficult to make it read as a description of the result you get. jQuery does the latter reasonably well IMO.

Comment: cross browser JS is a trivial thing, supporting legacy browsers is non-trivial. [jQuery is an ugly library](https://gist.github.com/1417030), I personally prefer the DOM interfaces. There are projects like the [DOM-shim](https://github.com/raynos/dom-shim) that are a far cleaner way to handle legacy browsers. I find well written code readable, jQuery and any code written using it is not. Any code written using vanilla JS and sensible functions is.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on implementation, but in principle I don't think there will be any noticeable difference in performance. Since you're using jQuery to loop, the `i` variable will be in the function scope in the first case, and in the outer scope in the second case. That might have a slightly different effect on memory allocation, but I doubt it would be noticeable. The only way to be sure it choosing an implementation and trying to measure the performance in it.

Answer (score 0):

These are potentially semantically different so this is an apples to oranges comparison:
e.g. if you were using `i` inside ajax callbacks instead of synchronously you would almost certainly be using the last assignment to `i` several times, rather than each of the different values if you made this change.

**pure speculation follows:**

Consequently we know that if you were using the full potential of the `var` inside form you would need different memory addresses for each `i`, then it must be doing more work.

It would take significant analysis to determine that `$.each` uses it's callback argument synchronously. Consequently, *if* this is a valid optimisation, I suspect most JS compilers will not be able to make it, and making it by hand should give you (constant time) speed and memory improvements.

**Other considerations:**

More lexical scopes potentially mean linearly increasing cost of looking up a variable.